# Unable to remove certain characters between values in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I am trying to remove characters starting from (and including) `rgm` up to (and including) `;1.`.

#### Example input string:

```
Sum ({rgmdaerudsb;1.Total_Value}, {rgmdaerub;1.Major_Value})
```

#### Code:

```
string strEx = "Sum ({rgmdaerudsb;1.Total_Value}, {rgmdaerub;1.Major_Value})";
strEx = strEx.Substring(0, strEx.LastIndexOf("rgm")) + 
        strEx.Substring(strEx.LastIndexOf(";1.") + 3);
```

#### Result:

```
Sum ({rgmdaerub;1.Total_Value}, {.Major_Value})
```

#### Expected result:

```
Sum ({Total_Value}, {Major_Value})
```

**Note:** only `rgm and ;1.` will remain static and characters between them will vary.

Comment: Please rewrite this as a [mcve]. It's hard to follow "code, results, code" rather than "all the code, ready to run; results". (Fundamentally this feels like a regex would be more useful here... How are you expecting that code running *once* to replace *two* values?)

Comment: How about `strEx = strEx.Replace("rgmdaerub;1.", "")`

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner, but why do you write your solution as a comment?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre - only `rgm` and `;1.` will remain static and characters between them will vary.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti for the reason that has just become clear, I was not 100% sure that it would answer OP's question, so I commented it in case - it also isn't a full answer but more of a suggestion :)

Comment: @mikemind In that case, you could try a regex replace - `Regex rX = new Regex(@"rgm\w+;1\.");` and then `strEX = rX.Replace(strEx, "");`. This assumes that only letters will be in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use Regex for this purpose. Try this:

```
string input = "Sum ({rgmdaerudsb;1.Total_Value}, {rgmdaerub;1.Major_Value})";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"rgm.*?;1\.", "");
```

Explanation:

The second parameter of Regex.Replace takes the pattern that consists of the following:

- **rgm** (your starting string)
- **.** (dot - meaning any character)
- ***?** (the preceding symbol can occure zero or more times, but stops at the first possible match (shortest))
- **;1.** (your ending string - the dot needed to be escaped, otherwise it would mean any character)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RegEx, with an expression like `"rgm(.);1\."`. That's just off the top of my head, you will have to verify the exact regular expression that matches your pattern. Then, use RegEx.Replace() with it.